# File extension for Markdown files?

Tags: file-extension, markdown

Is there an official file extension for standalone Markdown files?

Comment: Does anyone use `filename.md.txt` in the same way as `filename.rst.txt`?  It indicates that it's markdown format, but also falls back to plain text if you don't have something to handle markdown. GitHub recognizes `.rst.txt`, but not `.md.txt`: https://gist.github.com/2770487

Comment: If you plan on storing these files on a Windows machine then I'd stick with an <= 3 character extension. This makes `.md` and `.mkd` the only commonly used options. Of those `.md` is FAR more popular so I highly suggest using that. Don't worry about machine descriptor files; they aren't that widely used and they should be perfectly editable in a Markdown Editor (just ignore the preview portion of the editor).

Answer (score 120, accepted):

There is no requirement for a Markdown file extension. However to ensure editors or parsers recognise a file is Markdown-formatted, one of the following extensions would be checked for:

```
.md
.mkd
.mdwn
.mdown
.mdtxt
.mdtext
.markdown
.text
```

There are websites such as GitHub that use subset of these extensions when converting to HTML so developers will conform to their standard.

---

**Examples of extension usage:**

[GitHub](https://github.com/): *.markdown, .mdown, .mkdn, .mkd, .mdwn, .md* ([source](https://github.com/github/markup/blob/b865add2e053f8cea3d7f4d9dcba001bdfd78994/lib/github/markups.rb#L1))

[Vim markdown](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown/): *.markdown, .mdown, .mkdn, .mdwn, .mkd, .md* ([vim-m-src](https://github.com/preservim/vim-markdown/blob/3a9643961233c2812816078af8bd1eaabc530dce/ftdetect/markdown.vim))

[Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/): *.md, .mkd, .mkdn, .mdown, .markdown, .text* ([source](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/readme-content-221449772.html))

---

**Further Reading**

The [Markdown mailing list](http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.text.markdown.general) has interesting discussions about this topic: [**1**](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.text.markdown.general/3698), [**2**](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.text.markdown.general/3827/focus=3840), such as this snippet:

> Markdown isn't meant to take over the format of a file, it's a way to subtly add information to the plaintext. Really, the presence of Markdown is metadata, not a file format.
>
> No one opening a text file will be confused if they find Markdown syntax, it's pure bonus. In this sense, it makes sense to use ".text", ".txt", or whatever other plaintext extension is relevant.
>
> An editor which knows nothing about Markdown won't care about the metadata and won't be confused by the variety of "non-standard" extensions, but will display and edit the plaintext just fine.

Comment: Bitbucket uses md, mkdn, markdown: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Displaying+README+Text+on+the+Overview

Comment: .md and .markdown appear to be the most common extensions in use at this point.

Comment: Little update on the extensions recognized by GitHub, it seems the list grew a bit: `md`, `mkd`, `mkdn`, **`mdwn`**, `mdown`, `markdown` – [source](https://github.com/github/markup/blob/8f436ff25b9a3df6e8c43d4c8b8d173dbf1f67d3/lib/github/markup/markdown.rb#L33)

Comment: my school editor supports mdn.

Answer (score 17):

The idea of MarkDown and similar light-weight markups is to be readable as plain text, thus they have text/plain extension (`.txt` or `.text`).

However, there are some people who use `.markdown` or `.mdown`.

Comment: Just for the record, Elements for the iPhone recognizes .md, .markdown, .mdown, .mdwn and .text

Comment: vim 7.3 recognizes .markdown and .mdown, so .markdown is the most descriptive one.

Comment: textmate likes many, including .markdown

Comment: Kohana uses .md

Comment: I've seen a couple of .md in GitHub too, and my Vim at the office recognizes it as Markdown (I've to check why it doesn't at home).

Comment: This answer is not as extensive / complete as the one with the most votes.

Comment: @Wernight: The [default vim configuration](https://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/runtime/filetype.vim#1091) only recognizes `README.md` as Markdown, not an arbitrary file with the `.md` extension.

Comment: Markdown is human readable but unlike plain text has specific rules describing how it is to be rendered in HTML. Even with the wide variation in existing Markdown implementations it clearly does merit its own file extension.

Answer (score 4):

[iA Writer](http://www.iawriter.com/) uses the extension .md for Markdown content.

Answer (score 4):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/changelog.html) added Markdown support in v1.8. It looks for `.md` or `.markdown` file extensions.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of one, but I think a precedent is set by the use of the `.text` extension on the [official website](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) to [reveal the Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/index.text) that produces the pages.

Comment: Just because the official website uses it doesn't mean it's a good idea, though.  `.text` means plain text, not markdown.

Comment: @endolith "*not markdown*": [Markdown isn't meant to take over the format of a file, it's a way to subtly add information to the plaintext. Really, the presence of Markdown is metadata, not a file format.](https://superuser.com/a/285878/1574717)

Answer (score 1):

In short, the answer is no.

If you are simply using markdown files as stand-alone files that will not be processed in any way, name them however you please. If you are using them in a system the processes them into HTML or PDF or some other format, then you need to figure out what file extensions that system expects for markdown files.

Also, in the context of a UNIX system, file extensions are not even mandatory. You could simply have a file called "README" in markdown format.

Comment: But `file` will only tell you that it is ASCII text, which does not tell *me* that I can run it through `markdown`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Geany, the open source IDE, when saving a Markdown formatted file, uses the `.mdml` extension. Strange that it seems to be the only one...